# how to transform a request's URL using a client-side proxy?

Tags: debugging, http, proxy, request

I have an application that makes web requests to a set of URLs with the same host name. For testing purposes, I need to have this application make the same requests to URLs with a different host name. I don't have access to the source code, so building a debug version with the modified URLs is not possible.

Is there a [lightweight] proxy application that can intercept web requests and transform their URL?

For example, if it detects a web request to https://some.production.server/path, have it transform and send the request to https://some.development.server/path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, use [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/). Click Tools > Hosts.